# How to pass data from html back to python file through an ajax script in order to render more data on the same page

Tags: python, html, flask

This is a Flask question.

I have a dropdown and a button. I wish to press the button and send the current value of the dropdown back to a python function. This python function will do some stuff and determine the further contents of the page.

If I redirect to a new page, I don't need to use any ajax and the selected value is being passed back to the python function fine.

If I don't redirect but instead try to render the selected value on the same page (this is my requirement), as far as I can tell from other posts on this site I have to use Ajax to call the python function, but it's not capturing the selected value.

Please also note the restriction that the page shouldn't rerender.

I'm really at a loss here as I don't understand the difference between the two situations. Any help would be much appreciated. I have decent experience with python but Flask and html are very much new to me.

See code below:

setup.py:

```
from app import app

# Data for initialisation of setup page
@app.route("/setup", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def create_models_dropdown():

    # Gets used to create the dropdown
    model_ids = list(range(1, 11))
    return render_template ("setup.html", ids=model_ids)

# Further data to be added on button click
@app.route('/test', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test():

    ###
    # Debugging

    print(request.form)
    # When redirecting to a new page, this gives ImmutableMultiDict([('id_options', '5')]) (or whatever value is selected)
    # So the data is being returned

    # When staying on the same page (using the ajax script), this gives ImmutableMultiDict([]) so the dropdown value is not being returned
    
    ###
    
    model_id = request.form.get("id_options") # succeeds/fails as per comments above

    # Do something with the model_id
    return jsonify(result=(model_id or -1) * 2)
```

setup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Wut</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        var $SCRIPT_ROOT = "";
    </script>

</head>


<body>
    <!-- 
        action="{{ url_for('test') }}" will render the new page and work as expected
        if i take it out, the result of running the script below will instead render
    -->
    <form action="{{ url_for('test') }}" method="post">
        <select name="id_options" width="300px">
            {% for id in ids %}
            <option value="{{ id }}" SELECTED>{{ id }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button class="get_result" type="button">Same page</button>
        <button class="get_result">New page</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result"></div>

</body>


<script>
    // This works in the sense that it calls the function
    $(document).on('click', '.get_result', function () {
        
        // Debugging
        // This was another attempt to get the value from the dropdown and pass it back which also didn't work
        // var model_id = $("#id_options").val();
        // console.log(model_id)
        //

        $.ajax({
            url: "/test",
            type: "get",
            // data: { model_id: model_id },
            success: function (response) {
                $(".result").html('<h1>' + response.result.toString() + '</h1>');
            },
        });
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your select doesn't have an id only a name. So your jquery which is using `id` i.e. `#` is incorrect. Add `id="id_options"` to your `select` element.
2. To get the selected value,

```
    model_id = document.getElementById("id_options").value;
```

or

```
    model_id = $("#id_options").find("option:selected").val();
```

3. In your Ajax code, you are not submitting a form which means you can't use `request.form`. Instead try `request.values.get("model_id", None)`

Comment: Yes, when I add id then console.log works and it is being passed back to the backend also. Thank you!